# Add border to Polyline in Silverlight

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, xaml

Can someone tell me if it is possible to add a border to a Polyline in Silverlight?

I seem to only be able to influence the Stroke and StrokeThickness, but I want an "outer" line around the interior.

Thanks!

Edit:
As requested, here is a polyline:

```
<Polyline Points="0,160 25,140 50,160 75,140" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="5"></Polyline>
```

Adding a border around the shape does not add a border for the polyline itself, as done here:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3">
    <Polyline Points="0,160 25,140 50,160 75,140" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="5"></Polyline>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to make a copy of the line, and give it a thicker stroke.

```
<Polyline Points="0,160 25,140 50,160 75,140"
    Stroke="Black"
    StrokeThickness="13" />
<Polyline Points="0,160 25,140 50,160 75,140"
    Stroke="Blue"
    StrokeThickness="5" />
```

If you want the outline to go around the ends of the line, you'll have to fiddle the Points a bit...

```
<Polyline Points="0,160 25,140 50,160 75,140"
    Stroke="Black"
    StrokeThickness="13" />
<Polyline Points="3,157 25,140 50,160 72,142"
    Stroke="Blue"
    StrokeThickness="5" />
```